# XE2 and using ulink

Tags: linker, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I would like to use ulink with C++ Builder XE2 to see if I can slim down the now ridiculous exe and dll size.

Has anyone gotten ulink to work with C++ Builder XE2.

Side note:  DLL in XE was 1.6 MB in XE2 is now 3.0M.

Comment: 3.2MB isn't too bad, though - and would using a different linker really shrink it?  (This question is a year old with no accepted answer, so could you report back on what happened please?)  Do you know *why* it's bigger?  My guess is extended RTTI or something may have a big effect.

Comment: I never tried ulink.  Too busy  :-(

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a drop in replacement. 
Back up your old ilink32.exe and ilink32.cfg
rename ulink.exe to ilink32.exe and drop it in to $(BDS)\bin
check ilin32.cfg and make sure all the paths are correct for your project's needs.